# Signal to Noise Ratio of a train of pulses

Tags: signal-processing, white-noise

My signal was a train of rectangular pulses consisted of eight pulses with interval between pulses of 36 s with a temporal resolution of 0.1 s. I added a Gaussian noise oscillations with zero mean and variance of $10^{-4}$. I used the following MATLAB code to generate the noisy signal:

```
variance = 10e-4;
Signal = gensig('square',36,288,0.1);
N      = length(Signal)
Noise  = sqrt(variance)*randn(N);
NoisySignal = Signal + Noise;
```

How can I compute the Signal to Noise Ratio SNR?

Comment: Signal/Noise?..

Comment: @  Dole,  As far as I know, the SNR is a number, but here Signal/Noise is a vector.

Comment: Calculate the summed squares and use those?